# Google apps script - Selecting sheet by a key instead of gettsheetbyname

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have about 50 sheets in my Google spreadsheet, and want to return different values from different sheets. However, I don't feel safe using the sheet names as a key by using getSheetByName as they are easy to change. I was wondering if there is any way to use the gid-ID  I see changing for each spreadsheet as key? Or something else?

Below is what I am using now:

```
var ssValve = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Key').getSheetByName("SheetName")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no native method, but you can build a function for this:

```
function getSheetById(masterSheet, sheetId) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterSheet);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets();

  for( i in sheet )
    if( sheetId == sheet[i].getSheetId())
      return sheet[i];

  return -1;
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, I'll test it after work today!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! :) I'd vote you up, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation!

Answer (score 0):

YES! The gid is the unchangeable unique identifier for the individual sheets within the workbook.

It is surprising that you cant script with it as the basic identifier, Like GetSheetByID(). I'll be using your code in my sheets.

A suggestion to rename the mastersheet variable to something more standard like "spreadsheetKey" or "workbookKey".

Answer (score -1):

You can use `getSheetId()`.

```
var ssValve = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Key').getSheets()[0]
```

Change `[0]` to `[1] [2] [3]` and so on..for going from sheet1 to 2, 3 ,4 and so on

More info [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetId())

Comment: This gives the output I'm hoping for, but gives an issue that just moving the order of the sheets gives the wrong outcome. I was hoping for something more constant. That's why I suggested the gid-ID.

By the way, thanks for the suggestion. I try to vote you up, but my rep is to low :)